# What to do if images are not displayed in mob. versions of the online store on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJRT8.jpg)
Everything has changed in the computer. Same in the code. When I open the mobile version with F12, there are no images in the thumbnails and in the code there are old links to images that are not there. Downloaded WP Fastest Cache, cleared the cache, but to no avail.

Thumbnails, meaning small images that show the product category. Larger images are displayed in the mobile version.

Comment: Check with different browser and clear browser cache too. Without link we cant give you guide what could be. If this problem occurs after you activate this plugin. Turn it off and test.

Comment: https://www.yankids.in.ua/

Comment: The problem was before installing WP Fastest Cache. I installed it, thought it would help. In another browser the same problem, on the phone the same, images are not displayed. Not shown on mobile.

Comment: From what i see there are alot missing files. Reupload them.

Comment: Before turning here, I rebooted, opened in other browsers, opened in different phones. But everywhere in the mobile version there is no picture. The computer has pictures, the mobile does not. This is the problem. And I don't know how to solve it.